# ADO Command / Parameter no Excel (VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um código em VBA no Excel 2010 em conjunto com um banco Acces 2010.

Neste código, utilizo o ADO Command para manipular os dados no banco, porém estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro em um determinado trecho do código.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
Private Sub SalvarTermo()
On Error GoTo TrataErro

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim cmdAux As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Termo As String
    Dim Abreviacao As String
    Dim Verificar As String
    Dim Grupo As String
    Dim id_Termo As Variant
    Dim Acao As String
    Dim DataHoraAtual As String
    Dim Fim As Boolean

    Fim = False

    If trim(UCase(txtTermo.Value)) = "" Then
        MsgBox msgFaltaTermo, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Editar termos"
        Fim = True
        GoTo Fim
    Else
        Termo = trim(UCase(txtTermo.Value))
    End If

    Set cnn = ConectaBanco
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
    Set cmdAux.ActiveConnection = cnn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmdAux.CommandType = adCmdText

    If trim(UCase(cboxGrupo.Value)) = "" Then
        MsgBox msgFaltaGrupo, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Editar termos"
        Fim = True
        GoTo Fim
    Else
        cmdAux.CommandText = "SELECT tblGrupos.id FROM tblGrupos WHERE tblGrupos.Descricao = @Grupo"
        cmdAux.Parameters.Append cmdAux.CreateParameter("@Grupo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, trim(UCase(cboxGrupo.Value)))
        Set rst = cmdAux.Execute

        If Not cmdAux Is Nothing Then
            Set cmdAux = Nothing
        End If

        Grupo = rst.Fields("id").Value
    End If

    If trim(UCase(cboxVerificar.Value)) = "" Then
        MsgBox msgFaltaVerificar, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Editar termos"
        Fim = True
        GoTo Fim
    Else
        Verificar = TrataVerificar(cboxVerificar.Value)
    End If

    If chkboxSemAbreviacao.Value = True Then
        Abreviacao = ""
    Else
        Abreviacao = trim(UCase(txtAbreviacao.Value))
    End If

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblTermos.Termo FROM tblTermos WHERE Termo = @Termo and Excluido = False"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Termo)
    Set rst = cmd.Execute

    If rst.EOF Then
        If MsgBox("Deseja realmente cadastrar o termo """ & Termo & """ com as informações abaixo?" & vbNewLine & _
        "- Abreviação: " & TrataAbreviacao(Abreviacao) & vbNewLine & _
        "- Grupo: """ & trim(cboxGrupo.Value) & """" & vbNewLine & _
        "- Verificar: """ & cboxVerificar.Value & """", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Cadastrar termo") = vbYes Then
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblTermos.Termo FROM tblTermos WHERE tblTermos.Termo = @Termo and Excluido = True"
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Termo)
            Set rst = cmd.Execute

            If rst.EOF Then
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblTermos (id_Grupo, Termo, Verificar, Excluido) Values (@Grupo, @Termo, @Verificar, False)"
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Grupo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Grupo)
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Termo)
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Verificar", adBoolean, adParamInput, 500, Verificar)
                cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
            Else
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblTermos SET tblTermos.Excluido = False, tblTermos.id_Grupo = @Grupo, tblTermos.Verificar = @Verificar WHERE tblTermos.Termo = @Termo"
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Grupo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Grupo)
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Verificar", adBoolean, adParamInput, 500, Verificar)
                cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Termo)
                cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
            End If
            Acao = "cadastrado"
        Else
            Fim = True
            GoTo Fim
        End If
    Else
        If MsgBox("Deseja realmente atualizar o termo """ & Termo & """ com as informações abaixo?" & vbNewLine & _
        "- Abreviação: " & TrataAbreviacao(Abreviacao) & vbNewLine & _
        "- Grupo: """ & trim(cboxGrupo.Value) & """" & vbNewLine & _
        "- Verificar: """ & cboxVerificar.Value & """", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Atualizar termo") = vbYes Then
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblTermos SET tblTermos.id_Grupo = @Grupo, tblTermos.Verificar = @Verificar WHERE tblTermos.Termo = @Termo"
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Grupo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Grupo)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Verificar", adBoolean, adParamInput, 500, Verificar)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Termo)
            cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
            Acao = "atualizado"
        Else
            Fim = True
            GoTo Fim
        End If
    End If

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblTermos.id FROM tblTermos WHERE tblTermos.Termo = @Termo"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Termo)
    Set rst = cmd.Execute

    id_Termo = rst.Fields("id").Value

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblAbreviacoes (id_Termo, Abreviacao, Alterado) VALUES (@id_Termo, 'teste', '2015-02-02 10:10:10')"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@id_Termo", adInteger, adParamInput, 500, id_Termo)
    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

Fim:

    DesconectaBanco cnn, rst, cmd

    If Fim = False Then
        Call AtualizarLista
        MsgBox "O termo """ & Termo & """ foi " & Acao & " com sucesso!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Editar termos"
    End If

    Exit Sub

TrataErro:

    TrataErro "Erro durante a execução do procedimento ""SalvarTermo"" do form ""frmEditar""."

End Sub
```

Na linha de onde tenho o comando "Execute" (abaixo), é onde o erro acontece:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblAbreviacoes (id_Termo, Abreviacao, Alterado) VALUES (@id_Termo, 'teste', '2015-02-02 10:10:10')"
cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
```

A seguinte mensagem é exibida: "Tipo de dados incompatível na expressão de critério."

Eu imagino que este erro aconteça devido à incompatibilidade do tipo de dado do banco com o que eu inseri no meu parâmetro, porém no banco o dado é tipo "Inteiro longo" e já tentei colocar no parâmetro "adBigInt", "adInteger", "adVarChar", entre outros e mesmo assim não funcionou. Estes tipos de dados podem ser encontrados no link abaixo.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675318(v=vs.85).aspx

Será que alguém saberia me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

O problema foi resolvido. Eu não estava removendo os parâmetros do objeto command das antigas queries, portanto o objeto executava determinada ação com dados incompatíveis.

Adicionei os seguintes comandos após cada linha com "cmd.Execute" para remover os parâmetros:

```
For i = 0 To cmd.Parameters.Count - 1
    cmd.Parameters.Delete (0)
Next
```

Agora tudo está funcionando!